# CALayer animates with frame change?

Tags: ios, calayer

I have a CALayer I've added to my view:

```
myView.myCALayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
CGSize size = myView.frame.size;
myView.myCALayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
myView.myCALayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
[myView.layer addSublayer:myView.myCALayer];
```

When I attempt to change the frame of the CALayer after changing the frame of myView, the resize of the CALayer animates. I have added no animation to the CALayer, so I don't understand this. I've even attempted to call removeAllAnimations on the layer before the resize and it still animates the resize.

Anyone know what could be going on here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There is actually an implicit animation on setting some values for a CALayer. You have to disable the animations before you set a new frame.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

[myView.myCALayer.frame = (CGRect){ { 10, 10 }, { 100, 100 } ];

[CATransaction commit];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AdvancedAnimationTricks/AdvancedAnimationTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH8-SW3

Comment: Scotts right, but alternative to the second line you can use [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES] as short-hand to the key-value version. In addition, see "Animatable Properties" in the Core Animation Guide. It specifically mentions which animatable properties use a implicit animation on simple value changes by default. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimProps.html

Comment: Fresh link for Bobjt's comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html

Answer (score 10):

In Swift 4:

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
/* Your layer / frame changes here */
CATransaction.commit()
```