# iPhone :- Scroll down automatically on button click

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I searched here a lot but I am not able to do it.

Basically, I want to scroll below i.e in downward direction to check whether a coupon image which I am using is available or not. This is initiated by a button click.

This is how I create the scroll view:

```
UIScrollView   *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 440)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,500);

[self.view addSubView:scrollView];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(void)movedown
{
 [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,500) animated:YES];
}
```

it can be used to move down as upto 500 in y direction as u desired for 500 from `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,500);`

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction) yourBtnInScrollViewPressed : (id) sender
{
    [yourScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(x, y, yourScrollView.frame.size.width, yourScrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}
```

You can change the UIScrollView position as required on button pressed.

```
- (IBAction) yourBtnInScrollViewPressed : (id) sender
{
    [yourScrollView setContentOffset:CGSizeMake(x,y)];
    //set Your x and Y coordinates as you required.
}
```

You can change the currently codinates of your UIScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

I made a pretty decent post about automagically scrolling UIScrollViews. Maybe it can help you out a bit.

[UITableView scroll smooth with certain speed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979119/uitableview-scroll-smooth-with-certain-speed/7774732#7774732)

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)scrolldown
{

[scrollView setContentOffset:CGSizeMake(100,30)]; //change 30 if you want to see below images.

}
```