# iOS. UITableView -scrollToRowAtIndexPath blank content

Tags: uitableview, swift, scroll

I have a question regarding `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`.  It works ok, but sometimes, it shows a blank content until the selected row get's to the top of the `tableView`.  I read somewhere that it has something to do with the fact that the animation is running on main-thread.  Any idea how can I solve this issue ?  [As you can see, the same problem, without any solution](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zayds19f8m3li0d/Screenshot%202015-04-10%2010.15.35.png?dl=0)  Thanks !

Comment: Please don't open a duplicate of an existing StackOverflow question or mention a question without providing a link to the original question id.

Comment: Here is the link I got this information from : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979119/uitableview-scroll-smooth-with-certain-speed/5727153#5727153.  I opened it, because no solution for the blank content is given there