# Swift: Xcode tableView scroll indefinitely

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView in swift with ~500 cells. I would like it to scroll on it's own without any user input. Sort of like a stock ticker displaying information. How do I do this? In addition, when it hits the bottom I want it to start at the top again. Is there any methods or tools to do this?

Comment: It doesn't sound like the table view is really an appropriate view. If it's just a ticker. Should be reasonably easy to roll your own ticker with a pool of views that get reused and animate in the direction desired. SpriteKit would make this really easy.

Answer (score 3):

There is a method you can use: scrollToRowAtIndexPath: atScrollPosition: animated:

Here is a link to the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

Answer (score 2):

You may use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` and combine it with `animateWithDuration` method of `UIView`

```
var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowNumberHere, inSection: 0)
self.tableview.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, 
               atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
```

You can also use a timer to scroll each time to the next cell and when you reach the last cell you  scroll to top again cell by cell.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("roll"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


func roll() {
    // scroll to next row until we reach the last cell, in that case scroll back until reach the first cell
}
```

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979119/uitableview-scroll-smooth-with-certain-speed) can help but it's in Objective-C